# How to include SDL2 libs in Qt Creator Pro File on OS X

Tags: c++, macos, qt-creator, sdl-2

everyone !

I'm trying to import some SDL2 libraries in a Qt Creator project on OS X : SDL2_image and SDL2_ttf. Here is the content of my .pro file :

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

INCLUDEPATH += /Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers
INCLUDEPATH += /Library/Frameworks/SDL2_image.framework/Headers
INCLUDEPATH += /Library/Frameworks/SDL2_ttf.framework/Headers

LIBS += -framework Cocoa -framework SDL2
LIBS += -framework Cocoa -framework SDL2_image
LIBS += -framework Cocoa -framework SDL2_ttf
```

In the header file of my class, I put these lines :

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL_image.h"
#include "SDL_ttf.h"
```

But when I compile the program, I have an error in the file SDL_image.h. This error is located in the include section :

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
```

Some additionnal details about my configuration :

```
Operating System : OS X Mavericks
IDE : Qt Creator
SDL2 libraries
```

I think this is my .pro file that contains bad variables but I don't know how to resolve this error.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Can you give us the actual error?

Comment: Thanks for your time. The error is : 'SDL2/SDL.h' file not found

Comment: SDL2 as framework? On OSX you better off using `brew install sdl2`, header files are in a folder called `SDL2`.

Comment: Is in `Headers` actually a `SDL2` directory?

Comment: yngum : I'm going to try your solution.

Comment: Adam S : No SDL2 dir in Headers. Only the .h files.

Comment: @user3408272 Then just either a) create a SDL2 directory in Headers and move the headers in it or b) even easier edit SDL_image.h and remove `SDL2/` from the include statement.

Comment: Adam S : It works. I thought there was a "cleaner" alternative in changing/adding .pro file variables. But it works so thank you !